# How to get CALayer to be clear?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have this code that returns a CATextLayer to place over a video and it is returning blurry text. I have searched online and most people recommended adding textLayer.contentsScale but this did not work for me.

```
- (CATextLayer *)buildTextLayerWithText:(NSString *)text atPosition:(WatermarkPosition)position forVideoSize:(CGSize)videoSize
{
    CATextLayer *textLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    CGFloat fontSize = videoSize.height / 20.0;
    [attributes setObject:(__bridge id)(__bridge CFTypeRef)([ChannelsInterface mediumFontOfSize:fontSize]) forKey:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:(__bridge id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor] forKey:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fontSize] forKey:(NSString*)kCTFontSizeAttribute];;
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];

    textLayer.string = attributedString;
    CGSize textLayerSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    textLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    [textLayer setFrame:getFrameForPosition(textLayerSize, videoSize, position)];
    textLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    textLayer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
    textLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    textLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    [textLayer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
    [textLayer setShouldRasterize:YES];

    return textLayer;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the blurriness?

Comment: Why are you rasterizing? - Why are you adding a shadow? Shadows are blurry.

Comment: Are you using the right technique for adding the layer to your video? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool/videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithAdditionalLayer:asTrackID: